# Certiicado SSL APACHE -WAMP

Tags: apache, ssl, wamp

Tengo los certificados generados por goDady y los archivos .key y crt, sin embargo cuando reinicio los servicios no inicia apache (supongo que por errores), que estoy haciendo  mal?

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile c:/wamp64/SSL/kronoappwms.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile c:/wamp64/SSL/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile c:/wamp64/SSL/DigiCertCA.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

El Log me muestra esto:

```
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Tue Oct 03 11:36:43.235217 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 10296:tid 324] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Oct 03 11:36:43.404227 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 10296:tid 324] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Oct 03 11:36:43.425228 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10296:tid 324] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 03 11:36:43.425228 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10296:tid 324] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:43:51
[Tue Oct 03 11:36:43.425228 2017] [core:notice] [pid 10296:tid 324] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.23\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23'
[Tue Oct 03 11:36:43.426228 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10296:tid 324] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9040
[Tue Oct 03 11:36:43.877254 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 9040:tid 216] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Oct 03 11:36:44.029263 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 9040:tid 216] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Oct 03 11:36:44.050264 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9040:tid 216] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:03.760414 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10296:tid 324] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:05.760528 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9040:tid 216] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:05.778529 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10296:tid 324] AH00430: Parent: Child process 9040 exited successfully.
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:07.159608 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12156:tid 324] AH02577: Init: SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32 (key file C:/wamp64/SSL/server.key)
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:07.159608 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12156:tid 324] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:07.159608 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12156:tid 324] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key localhost:443:0, check C:/wamp64/SSL/server.key
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:07.159608 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12156:tid 324] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:07.159608 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12156:tid 324] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:07.159608 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12156:tid 324] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:07.159608 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12156:tid 324] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:07.159608 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12156:tid 324] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:07.159608 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12156:tid 324] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Oct 03 11:44:07.159608 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12156:tid 324] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Comment: Buenas a mi me esta pasando lo mismo, alguna sugerencia o motivo por el cual no se pueda iniciar el apache?

Comment: Esta pregunta es antigua y no tiene ninguna respuesta, pero por el log que deja parece ser que es un problema con el encoding, Intenta pegar el log de tu caso para ver si alguien puede ayudarte. Un saludo